# FilePicker keeps crashing in gallery (WP 8.1 RT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have an Windows Phone 8.1 RT application, in which I use the `FilePicker` API to select images from the gallery. However, the app keeps crashing when the user is selecting images in the gallery.

The application crashes under two different scenarios:

1. The user opens filepicker to browse through the images in the gallery, and while browsing itself the app terminates and the gallery is closed (home screen of WP 8.1 is shown).
2. The user selects some file(s) and presses the done button, at which moment the app begins to resume, but while resuming it fails and crashes (home screen is shown).

The filepicker works fine otherwise, but the above two crashes keep occurring intermittently. Is there any fix to these crashes?

Comment: Looks like the crash is happening because of how your app is handling suspension/resuming. When your app calls the filepicker UI, WP will suspend your app if it needs resources (RAM/CPU). I would suggest providing us with more info on how u r handling app suspension and resuming. Also, do u see any exception messages in the output window in visual studio?

Comment: @Flipper: any solution you can post for the same?

Comment: @vITs added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app was crashing because the `OnSuspending()` method was taking too much time to complete execution. Because of this, the OS kept terminating the app.

The scenarios under which the application crashed are as follows:

1. The `FilePicker` API is called and the user is navigated to the gallery view. Meanwhile, the `OnSuspending()` method is still executing, and due to a `lock` in the method which required waiting, the method never returned, forcing the OS to terminate the app forcefully, while the user was still in gallery view. The force kill by the OS essentially terminated the `FilePicker` API as well, and the gallery view was also closed, bringing the user back to the home screen.
2. This scenario is similar to above. Except, the OS doesn't terminate the app while the gallery is still open. Once the user selects an item from the gallery, the OS starts to resume the app and attempts to call the `OnResuming` method. But it realises the application hasn't yet terminated and the `OnSuspending` method is still executing (waiting to acquire the `lock` object). This mismatch in states which occurs when the OS tries to resume an app which still hasn't suspended results in the OS killing the application.

I basically ensured the `OnSuspending` method returned quickly to fix the above crash.

Comment: I have called SaveState just before opening filepicker, and using some flag not calling SaveState in OnSuspending method, as state is already saved to minimize time required.
Also I have added try catch in OnSuspending, should I remove the same?

Comment: @vITs Is your FilePicker crash scenario similar to what I've mentioned (it only crashed intermittently, not everytime)? I'd suggest you to log the time taken by the `OnSuspending()` method, and also insert a log line in the `OnResuming()` method. That''ll give you an idea if the crash is occuring before suspend, during suspension, while resuming etc.

Comment: yes...it does not crash most of the time..but crashes randomly...I think SaveState is taking time, so I done it before FileOpenPicker and on flag returning from OnSuspending event immediately. I am not doing anything except SuspensionManager.SaveAsync() by getting deferral.

Comment: I am getting same crash while doing in app purchase in live beta build when media is playing in background. I stopped player before in app purchase. This crash not comes in CurrentAppSimulator but in CurrentApp as it need network before launching store product for purchase, have you come across such case?

Comment: @vITs No, never used `CurrentAppSimulator` API. My crash was a failed resume when `FilePicker` suspended the app.